# accessing a javascript var outside of script in the body

Tags: javascript, razor

I am stuck in accessing a javascript variable for an if statement in a .cshtml file

Here is what I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        const preloadSupported = () => {
          const link = document.createElement('link');
          const relList = link.relList;
          if (!relList || !relList.supports)
            return false;
          return relList.supports('preload');
        };
        </script>
        @if (!Model.oldLayout && preloadSupported)
        {
            <link rel="preload" href="staticResource.js" as="script" />
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

the problem is preloadSupported is not defined and page fails to load. I am very confused as why this is not working. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: i'm confused why you think `@if` would work.

Comment: sorry, I updated the question @if was actually because the if had a model.oldLayout as well.

Comment: HTML doesn't have a built-in templating language.  You need to add the element to the document body in your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing server side razor code with client-side javascript.

Your line

```
@if(!Model.oldLayout && preloadSupported)
```

is checking both `oldLayout` and the result of `preloadSupported` on the server. But the `preloadSupported` function is on the *client*, so is undefined on the server.

Also (when on the client), checking the value `preloadSupported` will return the function's code - not run it and get the result. You need the parentheses after `preloadSupported()` to execute the function and return the result. Otherwise it will always return as a *truthy* if the function just exists.

`preload` is used to load scripts early in the page load process.

**From MDN:**

> The preload value of the  element's rel attribute allows you to
>   write declarative fetch requests in your HTML , specifying
>   resources that your pages will need very soon after loading, which you
>   therefore want to start preloading early in the lifecycle of a page
>   load, before the browser's main rendering machinery kicks in.

**Your options**

You could either:

Test for preloadSupported() before you arrive on this page (not that good) and pass back to the server for the user's session, cookie, etc. for later use.

Or

You can do it all client-side on the relevant page using

```
if(@!Model.oldLayout.ToString().ToLower() && preloadSupported)
{
    ...
}
```

(inside the javascript `<script>` tag.

This would output (depending on `oldLayout`'s value)

```
if(true && preloadSupported())
{
    ...
}
```

in the client side `<script>` tag.

Finally, place some dynamic javascript file loading code inside.

There are many answers on SO on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your answer, I tried to follow your advice and have something like this but this doesn't work: <script>if (!@Model.oldLayout && preloadSupported())
        {
            <link rel="preload" href="staticResource.js" as="script" />
        } </script>. would you please help me ? thanks

Comment: @AlreadyLost, do you want to mark this answer and put what you have now in another question?

Comment: sure, I can do that

Comment: Thanks again! Here is the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437508/combine-server-side-razor-boolean-with-client-side-boolean-to-include-a-link

Comment: Okeydokey, I'll take a look.