# combine server side razor boolean with client side boolean to include a link

Tags: javascript, html, razor, client-side, preload

I have a situation where I need to decide to include a html link based on client side boolean value and server side boolean value like this :

```
const preloadSupported = () => {
              const link = document.createElement('link');
              const relList = link.relList;
              if (!relList || !relList.supports)
                return false;
              return relList.supports('preload');
            };

if (!@Model.oldLayout && preloadSupported())
{
    <link rel="preload" href="staticResource.js" as="script" />
}
```

or

```
if (@Model.oldLayout) //server side boolean
{
    if (preloadSupported()) // client side boolean
    {
        @foreach (var url in Model.cssUrls)
        {
            <link rel="preload" href="@Html.StaticFile(url)" as="script"/>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        @foreach (var url in Model.cssUrls)
        {
            <link rel="prefetch" href="@Html.StaticFile(url)"/>
        }
    }   
}
```

how should I do that? I tried different variations none of them worked! thanks for your help in advance

Comment: In Razor to access javascript variables you place @: in front of the name of your javascript variable.

Comment: I tried like this  if (!@Model.oldLayout && @:preloadSupported())
        {
            <link rel="preload" href="staticResource.js" as="script" />
        } but in the file @: is getting red underline and the page doesn't load. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Is preloadSupported a variable or a function, because currently you are placing open/closing parenthesis on the end of it.

Comment: updated the question, it is a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place this code in your razor file inside your javascript tags for the client.

Pass in the urls for the scripts from the server, or hard code it in the javascript code.

```
<script>
    @if (!Model.OldLayout)
    {
        <text>
        if (preloadSupported())
        {
            loadScript("/scripts/script01.js");
            loadScript("/scripts/script02.js");

            function loadScript(url)
            {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                document.head.appendChild(script);
                script.onload = function()
                {
                    // Do anything with the script here (because it's now loaded)
                };
                script.src = url;
            }
        }
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think I can use it like this, these codes belong to prefetch page which is trying to preload/preftech resources before getting to page

Comment: They don't load before getting to the page, the page has to load in the browser first to commence loading scripts, images, etc. Prefetch just loads them into the head (where where all content must load before continuing processing the page).

Answer (score 0):

Mixing server side and client side code can be tricky. You can use rendered server side code with javascript, but it can't really work the other way around.

In your first example, the if-statement would have to be:

```
if (!('@Model.oldLayout' === 'True') && preloadSupported())
{
    //..link
}
```

The problem here is that the *link* wouldn't exist until the page was parsed and rendered. You could perhaps use `document.write`, `createElement` or jquery `$.load()` to add it, but that depends on what the external file is used for and when it has to be added.

Best bet would really be to check for "preloadSupport" earlier, or redirect the visitor if preload is supported and create a new response.